# Get notified when DTE.ActiveDocument changes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am writing a Visual Studio 2008 extension. I want to be notified every time DTE.ActiveDocument changes, so I can update something in a custom panel which performs a similar feature to solution explorer. I have yet to find any event which occurs when this happens. Is there such an event?

Concretely, I'm looking for something like:

```
var dte = GetService(typeof(EnvDTE._DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
dte.Events.DTEEvents.ActiveDocumentChanged += s => {
    // implies dte.ActiveDocument has changed value
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I belive you are looking for this event

```
_applicationObject.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated
```

check `GotFocus.Document == null` if you only interested in Document activation changes

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement [`IVsRunningDocTableEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents.aspx), register yourself as a listener, and then the `OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow` method will be called before a document is switched to.

```
class RdtEvents : IVsRunningDocTableEvents
{
    RdtEvents()
    {
        var rdt = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable));
        uint evtCookie;
        rdt.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(this, out evtCookie);
    }

    // ...

    int IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```